# QGIS Python console will not recognize any QGIS methods or properties

Tags: pyqgis

I just installed QGIS 3.6, and while the basic Python functions work, I cannot get the most basic GIS related functions working. Every attempt results in the "'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute" message. Here is one example:

```
    print(qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer.name)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'name'
```

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: try print(qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer().name())

Comment: Where did you get that `qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer.name` from?

Comment: Tried name(),same result. I picked "name" from the code completion list, which seems to be working fine. I get the same results with every example I try, however. For example, the following code fails on "getFeatures()".

Comment: layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer

features = layer.getFeatures()

Comment: This is QGIS 3.6 running in windows 8, btw, but I see the same thing on another machine with QGIS 3.4, windows 10.

Comment: @chriscalef you cannot randomly skip brackets when writing Python code.

Comment: Right, sorry, coding without all neurons firing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the method to get the layer and then call the `name()` method on your layer.
Something like this should work (as @LaughU says in comment):

```
print(qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer().name())
```

And

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer() # get the active layer
features = layer.getFeatures() # get the QgsFeatureIterator of the layer
```

Note the `()` after `activeLayer` to call this method and get it's return object (a `QgsVectorLayer` in this case). If you forgot `()`, you just get a reference to the built-in method `activeLayer` which doesn't have any attribute called `name`...

Comment: AH, thank you very much! Now we're moving again. My ticket has been resolved. :-)